# Einstein field equation from covariant derivative

Tags: riemannian-geometry, covariance, general-relativity, gauge-theory

I am trying to derive the Einstein field equations from this approach:

Let $\psi(t) = e^{-tM}$, where $M$ is a $4\times4$ matrix.

Then

$$
\frac{d}{dt}\psi(t) = -M\psi(t)
$$

Let us now suppose that I change $d/dt$ to a covariant derivative of the general linear group $g$.

A general linear transformation is given by

\begin{align}
  \psi'(x) \to g \psi(x) g^{-1},
\end{align}

The gauge-covariant derivative associated with this transformation is

\begin{align}
 D_\mu \psi=\partial_\mu \psi -[iqA_\mu, \psi].
\end{align}

Finally, the field is given as

\begin{align}
 R_{\mu\nu}= [D_\mu,D_\nu],
\end{align}

where, $R_{\mu\nu}$ is the Riemann tensor.

It seems to me that I now have a relationship between The Riemann tensor and the stress-energy tensor (as M is usually interpreted to be the Hamiltonian in QM and this is the total energy of the system).

$$
D_t \psi(t) = - M \psi(t)
$$

From here, what steps lead me to the Einstein field equation? I feel like I am almost there, but I need help completing the last few steps.

Comment: It would make it easier for others to understand your work if you were more clear about the physical interpretations of the quantities you are using, e.g. $\psi(t)$. How do you conclude a relationship between the stress energy tensor and the Riemann tensor from the equations you have listed?